# Permission denied error using datapsuher in CentIOS

Tags: centos, ckan

Installing/configuring the extension datapusher in a instance of CKAN (version 2.4.1) on CentOS, following the steps of the installation guide from source (production steps), install the datapusher in the default location, configure Apache, etc., starts apache whitin errors with wsgi module:

```
[Wed Oct 21 17:54:53 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=29799): Starting process 'ckan_gva_dp' with uid=48, gid=48 and threads=15.
[Wed Oct 21 17:54:53 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=29800): Initializing Python.
[Wed Oct 21 17:54:53 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=29804): Initializing Python.
[Wed Oct 21 17:54:53 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=29805): Initializing Python.
[Wed Oct 21 17:54:53 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_wsgi/3.2 Python/2.6.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 21 17:54:53 2015] [info] Server built: Aug 24 2015 17:50:06
[Wed Oct 21 17:54:53 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=29806): Initializing Python.
```

But when test datapsher calling to port 8800, try me back a 500 error, with the the following message in the log:

```
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [info] [client 10.115.100.69] mod_wsgi (pid=29800, process='ckan_gva_dp', application='ckan-gva:8800|'): Loading WSGI script '/etc/ckan/datapusher.wsgi'.
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69] mod_wsgi (pid=29800): Target WSGI script '/etc/ckan/datapusher.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69] mod_wsgi (pid=29800): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/etc/ckan/datapusher.wsgi'.
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69]   File "/etc/ckan/datapusher.wsgi", line 10, in <module>
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69]     web.init()
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ckanserviceprovider/web.py", line 50, in init
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69]     _configure_logger()
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ckanserviceprovider/web.py", line 121, in _configure_logger
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69]     _configure_logger_for_production(logging.getLogger())
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ckanserviceprovider/web.py", line 98, in _configure_logger_for_production
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69]     app.config.get('LOG_FILE'), maxBytes=67108864, backupCount=5)
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/handlers.py", line 112, in __init__
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69]     BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/handlers.py", line 64, in __init__
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69]     logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 835, in __init__
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69]     StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 854, in _open
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69]     stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
[Wed Oct 21 19:00:55 2015] [error] [client 10.115.100.69] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/ckan_service.log'
```

I tried to change the permissions on the folder /tmp (777), add execute permissions to wsgi script, check that all the dependencies specified in requeriments.txt are installed, with the environment for datapusher active, etc., ckan_service.log was empty...

¿Some idea?

Comment: https://tag1consulting.com/blog/stop-disabling-selinux